# Passing additional arguments to `odeint` from `torchdiffeq` to solve an IVP

Tags: python, ode, integration, differential-equations, time-integration

In Python I use the package `torchdiffeq` (as provided [here](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq)) to solve initial value problems. Given an arbitrary function `f(y, t, omega)`, I am wondering how to pass this additional argument `omega` to the `odeint` solver? From the documentation, I see that I can specify options such as the `step_size`, but I can't figure out how to pass additional arguments that are not the function `y` itself or the time vector `t`. Basically, something like

`sol = odeint(f, x0, t, method='euler', args=(omega,))`.

Does any use `torchdiffeq` on a regular basis and can help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use torchdiffeq, however there is an alternative method for doing this even if torchdiffeq doesn't allow extra args: use a lambda function.

```
sol = odeint(lambda y, t: f(y, t, omega), x0, t, method='euler')
```

Comment: that's a suitable work around, thank you @helloworld922